# CSV file to Excel

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, csv

I'm trying to scrape a website and get the output in an Excel file. I manage to create the Excel file but the columns are all messed up (please see the pictures).
How should I go about transferring the data correctly from the CSV file to the Excel file?

[image: CSV file]

[image: Excel file]

The code I used:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=34.05349000000007&lon=-118.24531999999999#.XsTs9RMzZTZ')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
week = soup.find(id = 'seven-day-forecast-body')

items = week.find_all(class_='tombstone-container')

period_names = [item.find(class_='period-name').get_text() for item in items]
short_descriptions = [item.find(class_='short-desc').get_text() for item in items]
temperatures = [item.find(class_='temp').get_text() for item in items]

weather_stuff = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    'period' : period_names,
     'short_descriptions' : short_descriptions,
     'temperatures' : temperatures,
     })

print(weather_stuff)
weather_stuff.to_csv('weather.csv')
```

Comment: your issue is that you've created a csv not an excel file. use `weather_stuff.to_excel('weather.xlsx')`

Comment: I think the reaseon why you have received a down vote is that your question is not clear enough. Your showing two screenshots but which of them is your output and what is the other schreenshot telling us? Is your question about scraping the right information or about exporting the information in excel? If the latter than see @Datanovice's advice. Else please clarify

Answer (score 1):

A minimilistic working example:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']],
                   index=['row 1', 'row 2'],
                   columns=['col 1', 'col 2'])
df1.to_excel("output.xlsx") 

# To specify the sheet name:

df1.to_excel("output.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')
```

Source: [Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)